# Outlook does not seem to be detecting Excel Attachments

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

What my current goal is that when someone sends me an email with the subject **`"SES Gas Matrix"`** My outlook will take the excel document off the email, save it in a specified location, open the excel, print it to pdf in two locations and then copy various cells off the excel document.

Then kill the excel document.

The issue I am running into is that my code works when I take document sent to me in the morning, download it to may computer and then attach it to an email back to myself. This is working perfectly fine.

The issue is when the email comes from the source, Outlook doesn't seem to be picking up the fact that there is an excel attachment on the email. I was picking up the jpeg in the email signature, just not the excel document. This why I have added in the if statement to filter for only excel documents.

This has fixed the issue of pulling the jpeg, but it still cannot seem to find the excel document that is clearly there. I can manually download it as well.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
    Private WithEvents myOlItems  As Outlook.Items

    Private Sub Application_Startup()
      Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
      Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
        Set olApp = Outlook.Application
        Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set myOlItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
    End Sub

     Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

       'On Error Resume Next

        Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim msgattach As Object
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim myXLApp As Excel.Application
           If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
              Set Msg = item

        Dim wbtemp As Workbook
        Dim testcode As Workbook

 If Left(Msg.Subject, 14) = "SES Gas Matrix" Then
    Set myXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    myXLApp.Visible = True
    If Msg.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
       For Each msgattach In Msg.Attachments
            If Right(msgattach.FileName, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
                FilePath = "G:\Betts\Floor Matricies\FIFOs\" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & " - " & "Gas Rates" & Right(msgattach.FileName, 5)
                msgattach.SaveAsFile FilePath
            End If
            Exit For
       Next
    End If
    Set wbtemp = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    wbtemp.Activate
    FilePathtwo = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - 5)

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    FilePathtwo & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    FilePathone = "http://intranet/Pricing%20and%20Rates/Floor%20Matrices/FIFOs/" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & "%20-%20Gas%20Rates.pdf"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    FilePathone _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    wbtemp.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5:L9").Copy

    Set testcode = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="G:\Betts\ReturnOnInvestment_Master_Backup Testcode.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3)


    testcode.Sheets("Floor Pricing").Range("A44").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    testcode.Close savechanges:=True
    wbtemp.Close
    Kill (FilePath)

   End If
  End If
```

I think it has to be something not necessarily with the code but how the excel document is attached. I am not very familiar with different ways that the excel document could be attached so that it gets by-passed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a beginner and more explanation is always welcomed.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see whether the correct lines are even being executed? BTW, if this code is in Outlook, you have a whole load of unqualified object references that are going to leave you with orphaned invisible excel instances running.

Comment: I have stepped through the code, and it picks up the one attachment (which is a jpeg signature), but then it thinks that is the only attachment. so it jumps right over the save as command in the for loop. Then FilePath is empty and it bugs when you try to open the non existent file. I am not sure how to fix the unqualified objects.

Comment: So what does `Msg.Attachments.Count` equal? 1?

Comment: It is saying two attachments. Is there a way to figure out what the two are?

Comment: Check `msgattach.FileName` for each one in the loop.

Comment: Oh Rory, I figured it out. The excel document was the second attachment and I had it in the code "Exit For" after the first attachment, which was the jpeg. Thank you so much for your help. Would not of figured that out without you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114759/discussion-between-david-betts-and-rory).

Comment: I thought this was solved?

Comment: My initial question was solved, I just had one more question regarding the handling of the orphaned excel applications.

Answer (score 2):

All Credit to Rory,

I had an additional "Exit For" in my for loop which was causing the loop to exit after it picked up the jpeg image so it seemed like it was not reading the excel document. Fixed For loop:

```
 If Msg.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each msgattach In Msg.Attachments
        If Right(msgattach.FileName, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
            FilePath = "G:\Betts\Floor Matricies\FIFOs\" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & " - " & "Gas Rates" & Right(msgattach.FileName, 5)
            msgattach.SaveAsFile FilePath
        End If
   Next
 End If
```

Best of luck to everyone. Thank you again.